# Google Play Store: Package file was not signed correctly

Tags: google-play-store, 4.2-jelly-bean, lenovo

I'm using Lenovo A369i and my Android version is 4.2.2. When I install an app, after it's finished installing, an error appears,

> Package file was not signed correctly

First time, I thought maybe it's my connection problem. But when I try it again, Google Play Store shows the same error. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is an issue with the Play Store, and not your specific device.  Probably the best bet is to just wait, and try again later.  You could also use the Play Store customer support to complain (which might get the issue elevated in their internal bug queue).

Bottom line, it's not you, it's them.

Comment: thanks booger..i'm try to contact play store customer support but they don't give any responds...any suggestion??